# Running script using python3 instead of default python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, scrapy

I have written a python program to scrape certain websites... I am using [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) which is a python framework.

I have setup the following cron job to run the scraping program:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
PATH=/usr/local/bin
1 6 * * * cd /home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper && /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/scrapy crawl my_spider >> /tmp/scraper.log 2>&1
```

The above program is using python 2.7. I want it to be run using python3...

I have install python3 and pip3 and have added the following alias to .bashrc:

```
# .bashrc
alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```

But when the cronttab is executed, I am getting the following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper/my_scraper/spiders/spider.py", line 3, in <module>
    from python_json_config import ConfigBuilder
```

The error message shows that my program is being run by python 2.7

This program used to work fine with Python 2, but I have added `python_json_config` import and I am not able to install this package using python 2.. that's why I want to run the program using python3

### Background

I don't need to update the Puthon version, I just need to run the scrapy script using python 3. I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3) question and the accepted answer here changes the .bashrc, that's why I did that.

I installed python using apt-get and installed scrapy using pip... I had not added any alias in .bashrc at the time of installation.

My Ubuntu server is an Amazon EC2 and I connect to to it using Putty.

Comment: Did you install `scrapy` using `pip` or `pip3`?

Comment: Have you tried to use a hashbang as first line of your cron job? Like: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: @Selcuk: I installed scrapy using `pip`... it was after the installation that I added the `alias pip=pip3` to `.bashrc`

Comment: @Danizavtz: thanks... no I have not tried that... if I add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to the crontab, will it apply to all the jobs  in crontab file? is there anyway to make `#!/usr/bin/env python3` apply to only this specific job?

Comment: You seem to have installed the Python 2 version of scrapy. Uninstall it using `pip2 uninstall scrapy` and reinstall it for Python 3: `pip3 install scrapy`.

Comment: @Selcuk: thanks a lot... you are right I had installed scrapy using pip2... after reinstalling using pip3 the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu has a special line that stops `.bashrc` from running in non-interactive shells.

You can change this behavior [easily](https://askubuntu.com/questions/955415/bashrc-shell-script-and-crontab/1080812#1080812), and add a line to run the `.bashrc` before you run the script:

```
1 6 * * * source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc && cd /home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper && /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/scrapy crawl my_spider >> /tmp/scraper.log 2>&1
```

Another option is to modify the cronjob line to execute the script directly using Python 3:

```
1 6 * * * cd /home/ubuntu/scrapers/my_scraper &&  python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/scrapy crawl my_spider >> /tmp/scraper.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking maybe second option might better? I would leave python 2 as default and run this specific script using python3?

Comment: Python 2 is deprecated and removed from Ubuntu 20.04, but if you use old version of Ubuntu it might be a better choice (when you come to think about it stability-wise)

Comment: Thanks for this... my server is Ubuntu 18... let me give the second option a try...